# getting certain bits from hex value

Tags: c++, hex

Im trying to get bits 6 to 15 of a hex value in c++. Im using & 0xFFC0, and when i print the value of those bits im getting values over 1024. but since its 10 bits the highest value that can be accessed is 1024, correct?

I have a 32 bit address which is 
    tag = 31 to 16
    index = 15 to 6
    offset = 5 to 0

my code looks like this

```
long long offset = address & 0x1F;
long long index = address &0xFFC0;
long long tag = address & 0xFFFF0000;
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a *shift* operations to bring that value down to the range you seek.

Comment: `0xFFFF0000` + `0xFFC0` + `0x1F` = `0xFFFFFFDF`.  Just thought I'd mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your address is a 32-bit bitfield, I would suggest making a simple wrapper struct, which can be constructed from and/or converted to a `uint32_t`.

```
struct Addr {
    uint32_t offset :  6;
    uint32_t index  : 10;
    uint32_t tag    : 16;

    Addr(uint32_t addr);

    operator uint32_t();

    void output();
};

Addr::Addr(uint32_t addr)
  : offset(addr & 0x3F),
    index((addr & 0xFFC0) >> 6),
    tag((addr & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16)
{}


Addr::operator uint32_t() {
    return ((offset) | (index << 6) | (tag << 16));
}


void Addr::output() {
    // Weird tabs & spacing are to guarantee proper formatting (in GCC testing environment).
    std::cout << "Offset: " << std::dec << offset << "\t\t("  << std::hex << offset << ")\n"
              << "Index:  " << std::dec << index  << "   \t(" << std::hex << index  << ")\n"
              << "Tag:    " << std::dec << tag    << (tag > 999 ? "\t(" : "\t\t(")
                                                              << std::hex << tag    << ")\n";

}
```

This allows you to use the address as a 32-bit value, while also isolating each component as a distinct variable.

This allows you to:

- Construct from `uint32_t`:

  ```
  Addr addr = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  ```
- Use as `uint32_t`:

  ```
  std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<uint32_t>(addr) << '\n';
  ```
- Assign to fields individually:

  ```
  addr.offset = 0x1A;
  addr.index  = 0x32F;
  ```

See it in action [here](http://ideone.com/dYIXX5), or [here](http://ideone.com/ftR5Ol) if you want the hex output to be lined up with its actual location in the address.

Answer (score -1):

0xFFC0 is 65472, so obviously

`address & 0xFFC0`

can be 65472 (more than 1024). What you need to get the i-th bit is

```
address >> i & 1
```

Which shifts the address right i bits, and now the bit you're interested in is the first bit of the number. Then you get its value by and-ing it with 1.

Comment: i dont quite follow, can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @user3678290 what didn't you understand?

Comment: so if i shift the address 16 bits to get the first bit of the index as the first bit of the address, then i want to get the value of the next 10 bits

Comment: Just repeat the process with every position 'i' you want

Comment: (address & 0xFFC0) >> 10, i did this but the values im getting are only in the double digits